# How to make a scroll able list of check boxes?

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, android-listview, development-environment

I am new to android development and I am making a recipe app. All seems to be going well but on the submit a recipe page I was hoping to but a box of checkboxes. For example, I would have a box taking up a third of the page that you could scroll through a check ingredients' checkboxes as needed. Is there any way to implement this? I am struggling massively on it. Thanking you!

Comment: I'm confused as to why you're asking this question.  The tags you have included pretty much already give away the answer.  You need to take some time learning how to implement a listview that uses a custom ArrayAdapter. there are plenty of examples online (and plenty good ones on stack overflow).  have fun

Comment: I don't know who to implement them. That's why I'm asking the question. Thought that was  pretty  obvious.

Comment: And I am saying that there are several useful resources online going into great detail as to how to implement them.  Anyways, here's a fairly decent guide. https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: no problem that site i linked https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki has several other beginner level guides as well. happy learning.

Answer (score 1):

Use List & Adapter.

A custom layout for adapter would fit your need.

Check this great tutor:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#tutorial_ownadapter